# what is a shapefile's measure value?

Tags: shapefile

I'm trying to write a GIS, and are using shapefiles from kortforsyningen.dk

I have the problem, that i cant find out what the m (mesure) value of a vertex is. 
I know x value is east/west
y is north/south
z is the height, elevation
but m, whats that? In physics, it would be time or 4.th dimention, but none of those fit with the word "mesure"

The Documentation doesn't tell, first time the word is used, it just says "plus a m (mesure) value. (page 10)

EDIT:
when i wrote "The Documentation" i meant the shapefile documentation, this one 
http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Comment: shapefile have geometric attributes (x,y,z) and user defined ones. Please find out what exactly you are refering to and post link to shape file documentation where "m" is described, "page10" is not sufficient!

Comment: so the m values are not "standard" but defined by the creator of the shapefile? if that's right undestood, please write it as an answer so i can accept that answer :)

Comment: m are standard, evrything in shp is standard, only th evalues in the .dbf files contain user data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m seems to be any value that you can assign to a point. E.g You measure the temperature at spefic measure points. then x,y contains the geo coordinates, an m the temperature. Then there is the PointZ type whoch contains x,y,z,m: which i undrstand as a 3d point with an assigned measure, e.g temperature or  airpressure, etc.